# Looking for alternative taxonomies (semantical tagging)

Tags: semantic-web, ontology

[**Context**]

I have been using [schema](https://schema.org) since I learned that this vocabulary was taken into account by most search engines. I like this ontology, but I find it quite poor and not well founded compared to some others -- e.g. the [Obofoundry](http://www.obofoundry.org/) [DOLCE](http://www.loa.istc.cnr.it/dolce/overview.html) or even [Wordnet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) -- I have been working with on an **academic level**.

For instance, it is quite easy to tag that somebody `knowsAbout` some `ComputerLanguage` (e.g. Python) but I can't find any relevant category for

- operating systems
- Web servers
- DBMS

That being said, I am aware of the fact that scientific accuracy is not the mere matter here. There are a lot of better taxonomies than **schema** but, if not "*aligned*" with **search engines** expectations.

[**my questions**] Are there other vocabulary as well supported as schema? Is there a way to use any published ontology and expect results? I find most SEO related articles on the subject deliberately misleading and vague while I am looking for a simple answer (and not some revealed truth)

[**disclaimer**] I have been using "vocabulary" "ontology" and "taxonomy" interchangeably. The academical nuance is irrelevant for the present purpose

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: Well, I do not display tags nor code in the question *per se* but relevant answer would definitly impact tagging choices. It's a question about how search engines parse web content to extract semantic information. I precisely wanted to level the discussion above the typical SEO related "*why isn't my website not blablah*". If the problem is the term SEO, I can edit. If your point is more general, remove the following tags from SO `ontology`, `semantic-web`

Comment: @JohnConde I just edited to avoid any misunderstanding. If this remain of topic, just tell me and I'll close the post